# Cell Element Background Colour - Conditional Formatting

Tags: powerbi

I'm trying to set a cell element to show as red if % is below 95%, simple enough.

But when setting the rule >= 0% and < 95% then Red as shown in screen shot.

As you can see, the rules have been set, however cells are showing red on everything except 100%

What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change Percent to number and try inputting 0 and 0.95